# Jquery UI Modal box makes page jump to the top on opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently using a Jquery ui modal box.

When I am slightly scrolled down the page and click on the link to open the Modal box the box should open in the middle of the page, the modal opens in the correct position but makes the page scroll to the top making it look like the modal is opening at the bottom of the page.

this is the code i am using to open the modal

```
$("#lightboxOne").click(function(){
   $("#example").dialog();
    return false;
});
```

And here is a the test url for the problem
http://satbulsara.com/NSJ-LOCAL-02-06/eqs1.htm

the link to open the dialogue is called **Show the Dialog**

How can this be fixed?

Thanks,

Sat

Answer (score 0):

After hours ripping out the lightbox i found it was a hidden div

Comment: What do you mean it was a hidden div?